# Web Serial Port Communication

Tags: reactjs

I want to communicate with a scale connected via serial port. How can I do?
I also tried other ways of writing the code below. But I can't tell if I'm having a problem with writing or reading.

My Code

```
    port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();

await port.open({
  baudRate: 9600,
  dataBits: 8,
  parity: "none",
});
readLoop();
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
const textEncoder = new TextEncoderStream();
const writableStreamClosed = textEncoder.readable.pipeTo(port.writable);

const writer = textEncoder.writable.getWriter();

await writer.write("W<CR>");}


  async function readLoop() {
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
const textDecoder = new TextDecoderStream();
const reader = textDecoder.readable.getReader();

while (port.readable) {
  console.log("port readable");
  const { value, done } = await reader.read();
  if (done) {
    reader.releaseLock();
    break;
  }
  console.log(value);
}}
```

Comment: What exactly happens with your code? And show where `port` is defined?

Comment: I forgot to add. I edited